# Package version and AssemblyInfo version

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, win-universal-app

I'd like to ask, what is the difference between package version and assemblyinfo version? Should it be the same? So if version in package.manifest is 2.0.5, so assemblyinfo version should be the same?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AssemblyInfo works just for assembly - exe or dlls inside the appx.
Package version is used to identify version of the packaged app (appx). It's used when you update the app - the new version have to be higher in order to be able to update the application.

These two versions are completely unrelated and you don't need to set AssemblyInfo attributes according to package manifest.

Comment: I would like to update package version every time I build the app, depending on svn revision. I didn't find anything. It is possible only with assemblyinfo

Comment: Are you setting CI build or are you talking about local build in Visual Studio?
There is some info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#applying-version-numbers-to-your-builds
You can modify and use the provided script:
https://gist.github.com/ridomin/7250c9fb3fbc74593c7f97520a3fe771
to change manifest before build

Comment: I'm talking about local build in VS.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edited my comment. Check the links, I know that's about CI, but you can use this to implement your own pre-build event.